# Unexpected GitLab page URL

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-pages

I had a Gitlab Pages hosted at https://username.gitlab.io/project/. I deleted and recreated the project (https://gitlab.com/username/project/) to start again with a clean history.

The page url is now https://project-username-longrandomhash.gitlab.io.
https://username.gitlab.io/project/ redirects to https://monprojet-username-longrandomhash.gitlab.io.

- How can I access my page with https://username.gitlab.io/project/ without redirecting to https://project-username-longhash.gitlab.io?
- Is this because I deleted and recreated a project/page at the same URL?

Comment: Dang .. it would be easy if you had access to the IIS console .. you might have to contact GitLab Support to see what their domain records indicate and see if they can patch the links?

Comment: It sounds like a domain verification record gone wrong. Try this: On the project sidebar, go to **settings** -> **Pages** and click **Remove Pages**.
After removing pages, wait until the pages site is no longer accessible. Also make sure you don't have custom DNS configured. After the site is no longer accessible, re-publish the site by running a new pipeline. If that doesn't work, you may have to contact GitLab support for help.

Comment: @sytech It didn't work, but you pointed my to the good page! I needed to deselect the "Use unique domain" checkbox. See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/introduction.html#enable-unique-domains. You can post that as an answer so I can award the bounty if you want. (Note: maybe related to this bug: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/426435 ?)

Comment: @sytech Would you like posting your comment as an answer so I can award the bounty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since GitLab 15.11, new projects will have the [enable unique domains](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/introduction.html#enable-unique-domains) setting enabled by default. This is a security-related change that helps prevent cookies from being shared between your different Pages sites, helping secure them against attacks that would be prevented by using different domains.

When you re-created your project, it will have been created with this setting enabled. Assuming your project was originally created before the release of GitLab 15.11, that would explain this change. If you wish to disable this feature, you can unselect the 'enable unique domains' feature in the project settings.

Answer (score 1):

I only see `project-` mentioned in the [GitLab Pages redirects](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/redirects.html#create-redirects) (configuration file named `_redirects` in the `public/` directory of your GitLab Pages site.)

Besides that, the [project website URL](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/getting_started_part_one.html#project-website-examples) should be:

- On GitLab.com, a project site is always available under `https://namespace.gitlab.io/project-slug`
- On GitLab.com, a user or group website is available under `https://namespace.gitlab.io/`

So you need to contact the support to understand where a `https://project-...` URL comes from.

But next time you want to start over with a clean history, you might want to force push a branch (`git push --force`), instead of deleting/recreating the repository: you will get less exposed to that kind of URL... fluctuation.